# Has_many through checkboxes (simple_form) not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to sort comments into events using a has_many :through association using checkboxes however the selected events are not saved. Here are my models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :categorizations 
has_many :events, :through => :categorizations     
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :categorizations 
has_many :comments, :through => :categorizations    
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :comment
belongs_to :event
end
```

My comments form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.association :events, :as => :check_boxes %>
<%= f.submit "Save" %>
```

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185347/rails-4-simple-form-has-many-through-check-boxes-not-saving), I added this to my event and comment controllers with no luck:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :title, :categorization_ids => [])
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :title, :event_ids => [])
end
```

It's hard to know what's going on though without recreating it or seeing server logs, Hopefully this will solve it.

Comment: If you don't mind I have one more question. Comments and events both belong to posts. Any clue on how I'd limit the events listed in the form to be only from the comments post?

Comment: You'll need to pass in a collection on your form and write a scope that does the sorting

Comment: = f.ass.. :events, collection: scope_goes_here